# Do any other denominations agree with the Jehovah Witnesses that Satan was cast to earth in 1914?

Tags: satan, revelation, jehovahs-witnesses

In my discussion with some Jehovah Witnesses, they claimed 1914 was the year referred to in revelation and that Satan came to earth. According to their belief, this is why from 1914 the world has never known peace: thus the world wars, famine escalated, and so on...

> **Revelation 12:9-12**
>
> 9 And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the
>   Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out
>   into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.
>
> 12 Therefore rejoice, ye heavens, and ye that dwell in them. Woe to
>   the inhabiters of the earth and of the sea! for the devil is come down
>   unto you, having great wrath, because he knoweth that he hath but a
>   short time

Are there other traditions that agree with this claim?

> 1 October 1957 Watchtower: “Satan the Devil failed to prove his false accusation against the chief Son of God. ... That is why, when the kingdom was born in heaven in 1914 and war broke out in heaven and the victorious King Jesus Christ hurled Satan down from heaven to our earth, a loud voice in heaven said: “Now have come to pass the salvation and the power and the kingdom of our God and the authority of his Christ, because the accuser of our brothers has been hurled down, who accuses them day and night before our God!” (Rev. 12:7-10) https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1957725?q=satan+1914&p=par

Comment: related: [What does this reference in the Watchtower Online Library mean?](//christianity.stackexchange.com/q/34623)

Comment: Possibly related: The [Philadelphia Church of God](https://pcg.church/) teaches that Satan was cast to Earth on 16 January 1986.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you consider dissident groups of JW tradition. 
In my research I have found at least 3 groups that share this belief to a greater or lesser degree.

These are:

[As Testemunhas dos Deuses Santos](https://www.facebook.com/testemunhasdosdeusessantos) - [Holy Gods Witnesses](http://personalstudyjw.blogspot.com.br/)
[The Herald of Christ's Kingdom (Bible Students)](https://herald-magazine.com/)
[The Dawn Bible Students Association](http://www.dawnbible.com/content.htm)

There are many other JW dissident groups but I could not verify if they still share this belief. Even because some of them doesn't exist anymore.

They are:
Laymen's Home Missionary Movement
Epiphany Bible Students Association
Laodicean Home Missionary Movement  (1957-1990)
Pastoral Bible Institute
Watchers of the Morning  (1937-1957)
The Christian Millennial Fellowship
The Standfast Bible Students Association
The Elijah Voice Society
The Servants of Yah
New Jerusalem Fellowship (1922-1992)
Old Paths Publications (1925-1961)
Forest Gate Church (1920-1979)
Goshen Fellowship
The Institute of Pyramidology
The Angel of Jehovah Bible and Tract Society
Berean Bible Institute
The New Covenant Believers (Berean Bible Students Church)
Associated Bible Students
Association of Free Bible Students of France
German Bible Students Association
Greek Bible Students Association
International Bible Students of India
Polish Bible Students Association

The year 1914 is used as a basis by Jehovah's Witnesses due to a calculation created by William Miller. As far as I know, William Miller used the same calculation currently used by the Jehovah's Witnesses, but it came to 1843/1844 not 1914.
See the chart below
[image: Original 1843 Miller Chart]
On the [2520 website](http://the2520.com/) you can see more details about the prophecy and Miller's charts.

Seventh-day Adventists use the verse of Daniel 8:14 to get to the year 1844 but no longer use the 2520 year count.

Both Wiliam Miller and Seventh-Day Adventists do not believe that Satan was cast to earth in 1914/1844. William Miller Believe that Christ would come in 1844 and Seventh-Day Adventist believe that in this year Christ started his work as a High Priest on the Heavenly Santuary.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question, since you haven't shown that any of the non-JW groups you mention believe that Satan was cast to earth in 1914.

Comment: @Nathaniel In this case demonstrating the _closest_ matches and explaining that the correct answer to the question is in the negative might be the best thing for this question. Whether its correct or not remains to be seen but I think it qualifies as an answer.  (And if the OP could [edit] to flesh out the idea as it relates to the original question that would be good!)

Comment: @Caleb Making the case for an answer in the negative may indeed be most appropriate here.  Elender, could you document some of the research you did that led you to conclude that no such examples exist?  That'd be more helpful to include for this question than simply saying "as far as I know."

Comment: Other "denominations" that believe Satan was cast to earth in 1914 are dissident groups of Jehova's Witnesses like the Bible Students and The Holy Gods Witnesses, as they have not much relevance and are not a worldwide movement, I think it's not worth to list them here.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting!  Allow me to kindly disagree with you – I'd suggest that such groups could certainly be mentioned in an answer as examples.  Regardless, a great way to frame your answer would be along the lines of "There aren't any *exact* examples except within the broader JW tradition, but here's something similar from the SDA tradition."

Comment: Being "relevant" is irrelevant—least ways it's not  for you to decide given that's what the question asks for specifically. They don't have to be worldwide movements to qualify here, but they surely deserve mentioning (and playing a more important role in an answer that some group that doesn't meet the basics the question asked for). Please [edit] this to note them and their relation first.

Comment: Ok, I'll insert them into the answer. Also I'll try to find other dissident groups and provide sources for my information.

Answer (score 3):

While I find the premise factually incorrect (see the comments), I think it might be important to bring up the fact that there is [a legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_to_Saint_Michael) that Pope Leo XIII had a [vision](http://www.stjosephschurch.net/leoxiii.htm) not long before that (1884). In this supposed vision, the Devil was given 100 years to destroy the Church. Other versions of the vision have this happening later in Leo XIII's life and saying that the Devil had "chosen the 20th century." Both of these legends are likely apocryphal.

As to the year 1914, once again, it is relatively easy to show that there have been few years of peace from the [18th](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1800%E2%80%931899) century [onward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1900%E2%80%931944). To my knowledge, no major congregation or sizable sect within Christianity holds 1914 to be any more significant than the start of a terrible tragedy. It is certainly not something which is held significant in the Catholic, Orthodox, Anglican, Presbyterian, Reformed, Methodist, Baptist, Congregationalist, etc.

To be honest, this more has the feel of [Harold Camping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Camping)'s dubious numerology. (When was the rapture supposed to be again?)

Answer (score 3):

The claim that 1914 has any such special significance is a vain attempt to point to some world event and claim it is the fulfillment of a prophecy in Scripture, where the prophecy describes an event that is invisible to us and which we have no way to know whether it has happened yet or not.  For this reason, you will not find this belief to be a part of Christian doctrine.  Quite simply, it is someone's interpretation, which is not authoritative, and the evidence for it being correct is so inconclusive (I probably should say non-existent) that you could never get a large group of people to agree it must be the case.

Unfortunately, I doubt it is possible to find credible/official sources that address this question, but the lack of sources, outside of the Jehovah's Witnesses, that speak to the issue - either for or against - should tell you something.

Additionally, I will point out that 1 Peter 5:8 says, "Your adversary the devil prowls around like a roaring lion, seeking someone to devour."  This indicates that, however Revelation 12 is understood, Satan has been active on the earth since long before 1914.

Use your own good judgement - it is probably about as good as anyone else's on this question.  Do you think a convincing case can be made for 1914 having this significance?  Why not any year before then?  Isn't 1913 an equally good candidate?  One could easily argue any for any number of years before 1914, claiming Satan came down then and was busy putting the events of 1914 into motion for x number of years.  Or, one might say the prophecy is yet to come; while there were indeed some bad times in the 20th century, things could have been far, far worse, and there has been a lot of periods of peaceful times since after WWII.  Even now, roughly 70 years after WWII, there are some conflicts here and there, but nothing in comparison to WWII.  Also, you might look at [death counts by war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_by_death_toll).  Given those numbers, the Mongol conquests may have killed more people in the 13th century than WWII in the 20th century!

Finally, I would encourage you to not miss the big picture of Revelation (God judges the wicked, the righteous are saved, Satan is defeated, Jesus Christ reigns victorious, death is no more...) by getting caught up in debates about things which are not clear and cannot be conclusively settled.

Comment: What you write in your second to the last paragraph implies that they chose 1914 after the events of that year had already happened, and because it was proven significant to the world history in general. But according to the accepted answer to [this other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/what-does-this-reference-in-the-watchtower-online-library-mean), that year had been pointed out as significant decades earlier and not solely by the JWs.

Comment: @coderworks  No, I don't imply that.  The point is, 1914 is past now.  If someone claims a prophecy was fulfilled then, we can look at the prophecy and look at the actual, historical events, and make a judgment as to whether the prophecy was fulfilled or not.  If someone argues that it was fulfilled, I would point out they could equally claim it was fulfilled in many other years as well.

Comment: ok, although in this case they had specific other reasons (calculations regarding the "seven times" of Daniel chapter 4) pointed to 1914 that subsequently turned out to be the year WW1 started. If those calculations had pointed to. say, 1900, 1913, or 1920 they could claim it was fulfilled those years based on something else but certainly not as significantly.  OK, that's at least my opinion as IMHO I don't think anything equally significant (equal to WW1) happened in 1900, 1913, or 1920.