# According to the Jehovah's Witnesses, where does the Devil come from?

Tags: satan, jehovahs-witnesses

I had two ladies come over yesterday from the local Jehovah's Witness place. They asked if we knew where the devil comes from but left when my wife said we're Catholic.  As a Catholic, I've got some ideas, but if I wanted to wow them if they ever come again, where do they believe the devil comes from?

[Possibly related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/according-to-jehovah-witness-satan-was-cast-to-earth-1914)

Comment: It appears to be similar to these [1](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-lucifer-and-satan-different-beings), [2](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/of-what-nature-is-satan), [3](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/where-in-the-bible-does-it-say-that-lucifer-is-an-angel), [4](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/who-is-lucifer-in-isaiah-14) and [5](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/do-angels-have-free-will/14229#14229) questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q.** "***According to the Jehovah's Witnesses, where does the Devil come from?***"

**A.** ALL of the beliefs of Jehovah's Witnesses are based on and found within the Holy Scriptures. The question therefore should more accurately be "According to the Holy Scriptures, where does the Devil come from?".

We who are Jehovah's Witnesses DO NOT believe that there are MANY ways to "interpret" the Scriptures, rather, being that the Holy Scriptures are **inspired by God THE Almighty Himself** (2 Timothy 3:16, 17) via His Holy Spirit which operated on the minds and hearts of the imperfect men He used to write the Scriptures (1 Thess 2:13), we who are Jehovah's Witnesses firmly believe that there is but only ONE WAY to "interpret" the Scriptures and that "one way" is to allow the Holy Scriptures *to "interpret" themselves* and not resort to *philosophical arguments* to evade its **clear statements of truth**. We simply let the Bible provide its own explanation instead of giving our theories as to its significance (1 Cor. 2:13). Indications as to the meaning of certain terms or doctrine are usually found *in other parts of the Bible*.

The fact is, contrary to popular but highly erroneous belief, God did not create the Devil. ‘Yet if God created everyone,’ a person may say, ‘he must have created the Devil. Who else could have? Where did the Devil come from?’

The Bible explains that God created many, many *spirit persons* similar to himself. In the Bible, these spirits are called **angels**. Also, they are called “**sons of God**.” (Job 38:7; Psalm 104:4; Hebrews 1:7, 13, 14) God created them ALL perfect. Not one of them was a **devil**, or a **satan**. The word *“devil”* means **slanderer** and the word *“satan”* means **opposer**.

The time came, however, when **one** of these spirit sons of God *made himself **the Devil***, that is, a hateful liar who speaks bad things about another. He also *made himself **Satan***, that is, an opposer of God. He was not *created that way*, but later **became that kind of person**.

To illustrate: A thief is not born a thief. He may have come from a good family, having honest parents and law-abiding brothers and sisters. But his own desire for what money can buy is what may have caused him to become a thief.

How, then, did one of God’s spirit sons make himself Satan the Devil?

The angel *that became the Devil* was present when God created the earth and later the first human couple, Adam and Eve (Job 38:4, 7). So he would have *heard* God tell Adam and Eve to have children, fill the earth and subdue it (Genesis 1:27, 28). He knew that after a while the whole earth would be filled with *righteous* people **worshiping God**. That was God’s purpose. However, this angel thought a great deal of *his own beauty and intelligence* **and wanted to receive for himself the worship that would be given to God** (Ezekiel 28:13-15; Matthew 4:10).

Instead of putting this wrong desire out of his mind, *he kept thinking about it*. This led to his **taking action** to obtain the honor and importance *he desired*. What did he do?—James 1:14, 15.

The rebellious angel used a lowly serpent to speak to the first woman, Eve. He did this much as a skilled person can make it *seem* as if a nearby animal or a dummy figure is talking. But it was *really* this rebellious angel, the one called in the Bible at Revelation 12:9 “**the original serpent**,” who was speaking to Eve. At Genesis 3:1-5, he said that God **was not** telling her the truth, *and was **holding back** from her knowledge that she should have*. This was **a hateful lie** and it made him ***a devil***. He thus also became **an opposer of God**, *or **a Satan***.

As you can see, it is **wrong** to think of the Devil as a creature with horns and a pitchfork who oversees some underground place of torment. He is really a *very powerful*, **but wicked**, angel.

Blessings.

~ ***NOTE:*** I am a dedicated and baptized member of the unified worldwide Christian Congregation of JEHOVAH'S Witnesses.

Comment: Good insight regarding Satan's desire to hinder God's design and declaration that the world be filled with God worshipers. Comparing the religious leaders of his day (and by extension all humanistic and political saviors) to sheep stealers, Jesus in John 10 cited their true motives, namely, to kill, to steal, and to destroy (v.10). Much like Satan, these false "messiahs" desire to supplant God's plan, which is to give his children an abundant life (v.10), with their own devious devices to further their own kingdom, not God's. To accomplish this, they often resort to violence and coercion.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from their '[Reasoning From the Scriptures Book](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1101989267#h=14)':

> "All of Jehovah's works are perfect; he is not the author of unrighteousness; so he did not create anyone wicked.  (Deut. 32:4, Ps. 5:4)  The one who became Satan was originally a perfect spirit son of God.  When saying that the Devil "did not stand fast in the truth," Jesus indicated that at one time that one was "in the truth." (John 8:44) But, as is true of all of God's intelligent creatures, this spirit son was endowed with free will.  He abused his freedom of choice, allowed feelings of self-importance to develop in his heart, began to crave worship that belonged only to God, and so enticed Adam and Eve to listen to him rather than obey God.  Thus by his course of action he made himself Satan, which means "adversary." -- Jas. 1:14, 15

Answer (score 1):

Jehovah made angels with a free will.. like he did with humans. So its just a matter of choice. Satan has chosen himself to become an opposite of Jehovah

for more information : http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2011171?q=devil&p=par  The article is on our official website and is called 'Did God create the Devil?'

Comment: Welcome! We expected backed up answers, not merely opinions. Please check out the [about] page. Hope you can contribute more.

Comment: i've added a source and article from our official website

Comment: Thanks, I didn't downvote you but I see where the downvoter is coming from. This is better but still needs more. Try to make it objective rather than an assertion of the truth and explain more in your own words rather than just a link. JWs are welcome here, so please be encouraged and try to improve your answer. Hope this helps.